# Using indirect function in an IF statement with quotes

Tags: excel, if-statement, double-quotes, excel-indirect

I'm making multiple IF statements that are going to have the same layout. Instead of writing the reference sheet name I'd like to reference a cell for the sheet name.

Also in the interests of laziness I'd like to drag the formula so it changes locations it is looking at on the referenced sheet.

At the moment it looks like this.

```
=IF(sheet1!O2="","",sheet1!O2)
```

Simple enough.

However I want to use indirect and I can't write it without getting an error.

Last attempt was

```
=IF((indirect($B$3))!O2="","",(indirect($B$3))!O2)
```

where `Sheet1` is in the cell `B3`

Doesn't work.

Any help on the correct syntax would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate $B$3 and "!O2" to generate "Sheet1!O2" as a string for `INDIRECT` to work, as below:

=IF(indirect($B$3&"!O2")="","",indirect($B$3&"!O2")

Comment: Brilliant!!That works exactly. Shame I lose the drag-to-fill function with the o2 reference (p2,q2..) but prefer the indirect function